# Heap implementation. Worst case extract complexity

Tags: data-structures, heap, complexity-theory

Hi I am learning algorithms using python. I was going through some sample questions in the book where it asks to show why the worst case time of the extraction operation on a heap  implemented as an array is O(log n)? I have no clue where to start on this and I am getting close to the exam. Could anyone please help me prove this? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you tried wikipedia?

Comment: Raul Guiu, Yes I tried Wiki, but I was clueless.

Comment: Assume a min heap. When you do extract min, you remove the min element which is the root in O(1) time but someone else should replace the min element and also maintain the heap property. So you do the heapify operation which takes O(logn) time. Heapify works by starting at the rightmost leaf element and going all the way upto the root while fixing the heap.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say we have a max heap. I will illustrate for n = 7, but logic is the same heaps of bigger size.

[image]
Worst case for extract happens when the root node has been changed to contain the smallest value of all the nodes (we extract the root in O(1) and put the last element in the array to be a root).

[image]
Now when we call Max-Heapify on the root, the value will have to be exchanged down with its child at every level, until it reaches the lowest level.

[image]

[image]

This is because, after every swapping, the value will still be smaller than both its children (since it is the minimum), until it reaches the lowest level where it has no more children.

In such a heap, the number of exchanges to max-heapify the root will be equal to the
height of the tree, which is **log(n)**. So the worst case running time is **O(log n)**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a min priority queue:

Disregarding the actual extraction which is `O(1)`, remember that when you extract the smallest value from a heap, you swap the last element with the first one then restore the heap property by comparing this element to it's children and swapping accordingly. Using heap property, the children of any node `p` are at index `2p` and `2p + 1`. So in the worst case, to find the children of any node, one would have to check nodes:

{ 2p, 2 * 2p, 2 * 2 * 2p, ..., N - 1 }

{ 2p, 4p, 8p, ..., lg<sub>2</sub>N(p) }

or

{ (2 <sup>1</sup>)p, (2 <sup>2</sup>)p, (2  <sup>3</sup>)p, ..., (2 <sup>lg<sub>2</sub>N</sup>)p }

So as you can see, the maximum number of elements to check in the worst case is lg<sub>2</sub>(N)

This was a pretty rough way of showing this property, I apologize